# Why use pip install requirements.txt instead of pip install ./?

Tags: python, dependency-management, setup.py, requirements.txt

I'm not very experienced with dependency management in Python but it seems that all of the dependencies in `requirements.txt` could alternatively be placed in the `setup.py` file under the `install_requires` field as follows:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=['numpy=1.2.3', 'pandas=1.2.3']
    ...
)
```

Since `pip install ./` using a `setup.py` file also provides lots of additional functionality compared to `pip install -r requirements.txt`, what is the use for the latter? Would a project ever have a valid reason to use both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pip install .` installs your custom package with all its dependencies. `pip install -r requirements.txt` installs only the dependencies.

Comment: Are there times when one would want to only install the dependencies and not the package itself?

Comment: Sure. You might have already installed the package, but not installed its dependencies. If you're working in a virtual environment or across many systems it can be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add `-e .`  to your requirements.txt and install your package with `pip install -r requirements.txt`